# Prove the series is divergent, real analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges conditionally. Prove that $\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty} k^pa_k$ diverges for all $p>1$.

attempt: Suppose that $\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges conditionally.Then by definition,  $\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges but not absolutely . Since $\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges absolutely, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is $N \in N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|\Sigma_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k| < \epsilon$. Suppose $a_k$ converges to $a$.

Then $|k^pa_k| = |k^p||a_k| = |k^p|a$.

Can someone please help me? I know there has to be a contradiction, such that  $|k^pa_k|$ cannot be less than $\epsilon$ 
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: It would be easier if you argue by contradiction and use comparison test.

Comment: You mean if $ 0 \leq a_k \leq b_k$ for large $k$. Then we have if $\Sigma_{k = 1}^{\infty} b_k < \infty$, then $\Sigma_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_k < \infty$?

Comment: Yes, that's the comparison test. I am thinking of $|a_k|$ though.

Comment: What would be good choices for $a_k$ and $b_k$? In proving by contradiction and using the comparison test, we would conclude the convergence of $a_k$? But isn't that known since it's given that $a_k$ converges conditionally.

Comment: Assuming the contrary that $\sum k^pa_k$ converges for some $p$. Then $|k^p a_k| \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$. So...

Comment: So we would have $|k^pa_k| < \epsilon$. Thus, so for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $ n \in N$ such tat $k \leq N$ implies $|a_k| < k^{-p}\epsilon$? right?